# Error: This version of PyQt5 requires sip 4.16.6 or later

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, pyqt5

During installation, pyqt5 doesn't recognized the latest sip version

**sip installation:**

```
sip-4.17$ sudo python3 configure.py
This is SIP 4.17 for Python 3.4.3 on linux.
The SIP code generator will be installed in /usr/bin.
The sip module will be installed in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.
The sip.h header file will be installed in /usr/include/python3.4m.
The default directory to install .sip files in is /usr/share/sip.
Creating siplib/sip.h...
Creating siplib/siplib.c...
Creating siplib/siplib.sbf...
Creating sipconfig.py...
Creating top level Makefile...
Creating sip code generator Makefile...
Creating sip module Makefile...
```

The correct sip version is installed

```
~/Downloads/sip-4.17$ sudo python3 configure.py --version
This is SIP 4.17 for Python 3.4.3 on linux.
4.17
```

**Pyqt installation:**

```
    PyQt-gpl-5.5.1$ sudo python3 configure.py
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    Determining the details of your Qt installation...
    This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.5.1 (licensed under the GNU General Public
    License) for Python 3.4.3 on linux.

    Type 'L' to view the license.
    Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
    Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

    Do you accept the terms of the license? yes
    Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
    Error: This version of PyQt5 requires sip 4.16.6 or later.
```

Any hint?

---

> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>   Description:  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
>   Release:  14.04
>   Codename: trusty
>
> Linux DSKTOP 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC
>   2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Try using the [--sip](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#cmdoption-configure.py--sip) option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed SIP using

```
make
sudo make install
```

and PyQt installation went smoothly